# Tools.jar cannot be found

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, minecraft-forge

I've tried to make a Minecraft Forge mod with Eclipse with a Gradle project.
But when I open it, it has some errors: 
 [image: My First Eclipse Minecraft Forge Mod]

I've tried to run the task `gradle eclipse` on command prompt (with a batch file at the exact same location), but it gives me an error that it cannot find the file `tools.jar`. I've looked up on internet that it's inside the folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\lib`, but I cannot find it there. And, on internet, it says that only Java 8 supports tools.jar.
So, my question is:
**How can I add tools.jar in that folder (link for download for jdk-16.0.2), or do I try going with Java 8 (needs link for download), or is there a way to ignore tools.jar missing?**

Answer (score 1):

`tools.jar` was removed from from JDK 9. You are using version 16.

In your case, it is better to install the version 1.8.

You could download JDK 8 from Amazon (Correto) from this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just when I'm free, I'll test it and see if it really works. By the way, thank you.